# Why IV shares an inverse relationship with underlying

Tags: implied-volatility

Why does implied volatility usually fall when underlying rises and rises when underlying falls?
Implied volatility is a length of one standard deviation. From this definition, is it possible without using BSM model to intuit why IV shares an inverse relationship with underlying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In index, where the skew is more pronounced, with focus on moves of say 2-3%, when they are down it is more likely they are fast, whereas if they are up, it is more likely that they are slow. For that reason, when you move down you expect the uncertainty (measured by IV) to raise, whereas if you go up you expect it to decrease.

Comment: I would just add that this is often due to increased correlations during declines, perhaps due to forced sales due to margin calls and other contagion.

Also worth pointing out that this is a very equity-centric point of view.  In FX, very often, there's a smile but no skew.

Answer (score 0):

think of option as an insurance and the cost of the insurance as IV. when the market goes down, investors would buy puts which drives IV up. When market goes up, ppl would exit the puts position, which is a declining demand. IV goes down.

Comment: Thanks. Can you use call option in your example, because it seems like when we use call option, a rising market means greater demand of calls,hence more IV.

Comment: In index, where the skew is more pronounced, with focus on moves of say 2-3%, when they are down it is more likely they are fast, whereas if they are up, it is more likely that they are slow. For that reason, when you move down you expect the uncertainty (measured by IV) to raise, whereas if you go up you expect it to decrease.